# numpy python - slicing rows and columns at the same time

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a numpy matrix with 130 X 13. Say I want to select a specific set of rows meeting a condition and a subset of columns -

```
trainx[trainy==label,[0,6]]
```

The above code does not work and throws an error - `IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (43,) (2,).`

However if I do it in 2 steps - first subset rows and then columns, it works. Is it something weird or numpy works this way?

```
temp1 = trainx[trainy==label,:]
temp1 = temp1[:,[0,6]]
```

Comment: trains.loc[...,...] ?

Comment: That 2 step indexing may be the easiest to underrstand and use, especially when the row index is a boolean mask..

Comment: I assume `trainy` is (130,) shape, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply chain the indexing like

```py
trainx[trainy==label][:, [0,6]]
```

**Runable Example**

```py
arr = np.random.rand(130,13)
arr[arr[:,0]>0.5][:, [0,6]]
```

Comment: That's not going to work with a 2d array, and a boolean row mask.

Comment: Thank you. Chaining worked. For my specific example - trainx[trainy==label,:][:,[0,6]]

Answer (score 0):

```
In [154]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)                                        
In [155]: mask = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0],bool)
```

With your two step approach:

```
In [156]: x[mask]                 # x[mask, :]                                                              
Out[156]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
In [157]: x[mask][:,[1,3]]                                                      
Out[157]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 11],
       [17, 19]])
```

Or the two indices could be combined with `ix_`:

```
In [158]: np.ix_(mask, [1,3])                                                   
Out[158]: 
(array([[0],
        [2],
        [4]]), array([[1, 3]]))
In [159]: x[np.ix_(mask, [1,3])]                                                
Out[159]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 11],
       [17, 19]])
```

Note that the first array in `Out[158]` is `np.nonzero(mask)[0][:,None]`, the nonzero indices in column vector form.  That (3,1) indexing array can broadcast with the (2,) column array to select a (3,2) array of elements.  Or in your example a (43,2) array.

The boolean `mask` cannot be turned into a (6,1) array and used to mask `x`; that would only work if it was turned into a (6,4) mask, matching the shape of `x`.

So either use the 2 step indexing, or use `ix_`.